# Replace a pattern based off of the integer in the pattern in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I'm trying to convert a bunch of `.textile` files into their equivalent `.markdown` files.

I would like a vim search/replace command to replace all `h1.`, `h2.`, `h3.`, etc. patterns with the associated number of `#` characters. So, `h1.` would become `#`, `h2.` would be come `##` and so forth.

I think what I want to use is the `\=repeat` command, but I'm a bit lost as to what arguments to pass it.

Here is what I have so far. It replaces the correct matches, but it just deletes them and gives me errors:

```
:1,$s/h\d./\=repeat('#',submatch(0))
```

**What are the proper arguments to pass to the `\=repeat` command?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line may help you:

```
%s/\vh(\d)\./\=repeat('#',submatch(1))
```

you used `submatch(0)`, it was the whole matched string : `h and number and any char (here you had another problem, you should escape the period )`, so it won't do what you were expecting.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Since the period matches anything, it also matches period, so I didn't actually have to escape it (although I guess I should to make sure I don't get non-periods...). Quick question though: what does the `\v` do? It seems to be what made it work, but I've never used that before.

Comment: @TopherFangio, `\v` means that the in the pattern after it, all ASCII characters excluding the alphanumeric characters and `_` have a special meaning (vim calls this "very magic" – gotta love that).  This means that instead of needing to escape the parens using `\(`, you can just type them.  For more info, try `:h /\v` and, more generally, `:h magic`.